# A build error occurred when I used Xcode to compile a example 'sync_client' of boost

Tags: xcode, boost-asio

I used Xcode to build a example of boost, but as you see followed it is failed. And the error 
I've got is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init2 in sync_client.o
      boost::asio::error::get_system_category() in sync_client.o
      boost::system::error_code::error_code() in sync_client.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in sync_client.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init1 in sync_client.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know how I can fix it. I've added the include and libs path of boost into Xcode Build Setting. Does anyone have any idea about this problem?

Comment: Do you link with Boost.System (i.e. `-lboost_system`)?

Answer (score 2):

Either link against a pre-built version of libboost-system.so or pull in libs/system/src/error_code.cpp (from your boost source package), into your project.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! I tried to pull the file, /system/src/error_code.cpp, to my project, and It worked. However I've no idea about the pre-build version of libboost-system.so to which you referred. You meant I built a incomplete one or else? Could you give me any advice?

Comment: if you use macports, you could: "sudo port install libboost-dev" which will install a pre-built libboost-system.so in /opt/local/lib, which you could link against. However, if you intend to ship the software to someone who isn't using ports, you would still have to figure out how to package the boost-system library. Or you could link statically against it.